# Django missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to make a view that i can use in multiple apps with different redirect urls:

Parent function:

```
def create_order(request, redirect_url):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(redirect_url)
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
    data['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'core/order_document.html', data)
```

Child function:

```
@login_required()
def admin_order_document(request):
    redirect_url = 'administrator:order_waiting_list'
    return create_order(request, redirect_url)
```

When i'm trying to call admin_order_document function i'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: create_order() missing 1 required positional argument: 'redirect_url'
```

If i remove redirect_url from both functions and manually add 'administrator:order_waiting_list' to redirect() it works, but i need to redirect to multiple urls. So, why am i getting this error?

Comment: what Django version are you using?

Comment: Django version 1.11.7

Comment: What URL gives that error message, and what is the URL pattern for that URL?

Comment: url(r'^orders/create/', views.create_order, name='create_order'),  the create_order function lives in core, i'm importing it in administrator views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url(r'^orders/create/', views.create_order, name='create_order')
```

This clearly is not going to work, since `create_order` requires `redirect_url` but there is no `redirect_url` kwarg in the regex `r'^orders/create/'`.

Perhaps you want to use the `admin_order_document` view here instead:

```
url(r'^orders/create/', views.admin_order_document, name='create_order')
```

Note you should add a trailing dollar, i.e. `r'^orders/create/$'` unless you want to match `orders/create/something-else` as well as `orders/create/`.

Comment: jesus christ, i accidentally put create_order in the url instead of admin_order_document, that's what i've wanted to do, but i wasn't paying attention

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't changed the regular url

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin_site.urls),
    ...
]
```

of your admin site you need to call your function like that:

```
@login_required()
def admin_order_document(request):
    redirect_url = 'admin:order_waiting_list'
    return create_order(request, redirect_url)
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: i didn't change the regular admin url, there is a different app administrator. in the main url:     url(r'^administrator/', include('administrator.urls', namespace='administrator')),

Comment: My fault, is `order_waiting_list` named `name='order_waiting_list'` in your `administrator.urls`?

Comment: in administrator's urls it's named 'order_waiting_list' so to access it i have to write administrator:order_waiting_list, but i don't think the url is the problem, the function just doesn't accept the second parameter.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the `create_order()` function a `reverse` object?

something like:
`from django.urls import reverse`
`redirect_url = reverse('administrator:order_waiting_list')`